# LDAP user can still login Ubuntu 16.04, but 17.10 after setting up the Password expiration date in Fusion Directory?

Tags: login, password, users, ldap

I set one LDAP user 'Password expiration date' to 08.03.2018 in fusion directory and the account status shows 'expired'

I tested the login via both Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 17.10 machine.

- Ubuntu 16.04 -- still allowed the user to login
- Ubuntu 17.10 -- blocked the user  'Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator'

also tested to login fusion directory with message 'Account locked. Please contact your system administrator! '

My question is why Ubuntu 16.04 still allows locked user to login ???

Comment: What client side package are you using for accessing the directory? sssd? nslcd?

Comment: actually, sssd is used.

Comment: I do not have both versions available for testing, but maybe ldap_pwd_policy (/etc/sssd/sssd.conf) is not set correctly on 16.04